# Hosting a webpage in one of my VMs

Tags: linux, networking, qemu, lamp

OK here we go, I'm trying to be clear... ahem:
I want to host a website in a VM into my Linux computer, so here is the setup:

my host is Linux Mint running KVM/Qemu/libvirt internal IP is 192.168.0.10, it is directly connected to my modem/router from my internet provider.

my guest is running arch linux and a LAMP server on u subnetwork in qemu at 192.168.42.5.

How can I access to that lamp box from the internet.
I have a no-ip account and a domain name registered, but I want to keep myself as secure as possible.
This is just for entertainement purposes, and studying, I've no intention to host really my website like that for those of you who might ask.

Thanks in advance, I'm a bit confused about networking and I am learning as I go, so please be gentle with me ;)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I access that LAMP box from the internet?

Note that the following are (extremely) broad steps:

1. Point your domain/NOIP at the external IP of your modem/router (create some A records for e.g. `1.2.3.4` or whatever your non-local e.g. home IP is).
2. Port forward port 80 from your router to your Qemu host (`192.168.0.10`).
3. Start Qemu with the option to forward traffic it receives on port 80 to your virtual guest (`192.168.42.5`).
4. Configure your LAMP stack (Apache specifically) to `Listen` on port 80 for your website/domain.

The biggest obstacles you are likely to encounter are firewalls and perhaps some routing on your host/guest machines.